# Поиск слов и запись в файл с помощью конвейера

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pipes

Как при помощи конвейера можно осуществить запись найденных слов в отдельный текстовый файл?

Имеется файл с набором слов, командой `grep "e" /home/user/file.txt`я нахожу все слова с буквой "e", дальше требуется эти слова записать в другой текстовый файл. Пытался сделать при помощи `sed`, но не получилось. Других команд тоже не нашел. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы здесь принято задавать по отдельности.

Answer (score 1):

*stdout* программы можно перенаправить в файл с помощью одного из операторов перенаправления — `>`:

```
$ программа > выходной.файл
```

например:

```
$ grep "e" /home/user/file.txt > /home/user/file2.txt
```

---

оператор «конвейер» `|` выполняет несколько иную задачу: связывает *stdout* одной программы с *stdin* другой:

```
$ программа1 | программа2
```

записи *stdout* первой программы в какой-либо файл при этом, естественно, не происходит.

но `программа2`, конечно, может записывать свой *stdin* в какой-нибудь файл. есть даже такая [специализированная программа, упомянутая в стандарте posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html), которая совершает ровно описанное действие — записывает то, что ей поступило на *stdin*, в указанные параметрами файлы:

```
$ программа | tee выходной.файл
```